# MySQL PDO binding empty result

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, binding

Here is my query

```
$sql = "SELECT sku, cost, fee
          FROM `mws_config_data` WHERE `sku` = :sku";
$config_select = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$config_select->execute( array( ':sku' => $sku, PDO::PARAM_STR));
```

returns empty result

But if I do hardcode `sku` value eg `AHX-32929-xxx` and run the query accordingly, it works and show records

i.e.

```
$sql = "SELECT sku, cost, fee
          FROM `mws_config_data` WHERE `sku` = 'AHX-32929-xxx'";
$config_select = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$config_select->execute();
```

Most probably a binding problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
tried both one by one, yet not working

```
$config_select->execute( array( 'sku' => $sku));
 $config_select->execute( array(    ':sku' => $sku));
```

my final step as

```
$config_data = $config_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($config_data);
```

**Empty result (what I mean)**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["sku"]=>
    NULL
    ["cog"]=>
    NULL
    ["cost"]=>
    NULL
    ["fee"]=>
    NULL

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$sku` is having values always? it seems like its coming empty. check by `echo` it.

Comment: dumped it, and its there

Comment: define "empty result". What particular value does your code return.

Comment: whoever is downvoting, should have some time to comment reason too...those guys atleast tried their skill to help me..

Comment: This site is not for "trying skills". If you got no answer, then you should comment, not answer. As simple as that. Care to read site rules?

Comment: you are right too, but as a help seeker, I would still encourage those guys, meanwhile I don't want to offend to SO rules and regulations..

Comment: How do you get this empty result? Raw PDO will never return anything like this.

Comment: can you show us your database structure ?

Answer (score 0):

In the binding `$config_select->execute( array( ':sku' => $sku, PDO::PARAM_STR));` you can try 2 things. Remove the `:` of sku and if that doesn't work remove `PDO::PARAM_STR`

EDIT:

You can do this

```
$config_select->bindParam(':sku', $sku, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$config_select->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$config_select = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$config_select->execute(array(':sku' => $sku));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I use classes most of time here an example

```
public function findMySku($sku)
{

try
{
 $sql = "SELECT sku, cost, fee
 FROM `mws_config_data` WHERE `sku` = :sku";
 $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(":sku", $sku);
 $stmt->execute();
 $myTableOutput = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::"here is your choice what you want to do and depending where I for example use FETCH_CLASS since my database is in my class");
}
catch
{
 die($e->getMessage());
}

if(isset($myTableOutput[0])
{
     $mySku = $myTableOutput[0];
}
else
{
  die("nooo sku found!");
}

  return $mySku;
}
```